# Write a double to EEPROM

Tags: c++, c, optimization, terminal, arduino

I work at arduino with eclipse. I want to convert a double to char array to store to EEPROM. From another question I found an answer to the problem. I changed it to meet my needs. But the number I get back is not exactly the same.

The code is:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "EEPROM.h"

char finalArray[8];
double final;
double d;

int main(void)
{
    init();
    setup();

    for (;;)
        loop();

    return 0;
}


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    d = 557.254;
    char* byteArray = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        EEPROM.write(i,byteArray[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            finalArray[i]=EEPROM.read(i);
    }

}

void loop() {

    final = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(finalArray);
    double diff=d-final;
    final+=diff;
    Serial.println(d,9);
    Serial.println(diff,9);
    Serial.println(final,9);

    delay(1000);
}
```

At the terminal I get value of `958.25402` instead of `958.25400`. And if I ask for 9 decimal digits at the print, instead of 5, I get the number `958.254028320`.
What is the solution?

the serial.print give the numbers:

> 557.254028320
>
> 0.000000000
>
> 557.254028320

So the problem is at the initialization of the double d.

Comment: If you insert `printf("d = %.17g.\n", d);` just after `d = 958.254;`, what result do you get? If, in the write loop, you insert `printf("byteArray[%d] = %#x.\n", i, (unsigned char) byteArray[i]);`, what result do you get? If, in the read loop, after each read, you insert `printf("finalArray[%d] = %#x.\n", i, (unsigned char) finalArray[i]);`, what result do you get? Is it the same as the initial bytes?

Comment: when i am interested on reading not printing the number cause i want to use is for calculations so basically i do not need to fix the printing but the returned number.I fixed the code and i will give you the result to understand the problem.Problem starts at the double d that i give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value 958.2540283203125 results from converting `958.254` to a `float` (specifically, to an IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating-point value). Converting it to a `double` (64-bit) should produce 958.2540000000000190993887372314929962158203125.

If the code is as you have shown here, then your compiler is not supporting `double` correctly (the C and C++ standards require that a ten-digit decimal numeral can be converted to `double` and back again without change to the decimal digits).

For a sanity test, you should print `d` **immediately** after it is assigned. It is possible that there is some “funny business” in the code that alters the value of `d` later. If `d = 958.254;` results in the value of `d` being 958.2540283203125, then you should investigate your compiler’s support for 64-bit floating-point. If `d` is 958.2540000000000190993887372314929962158203125 and changes later, then you should investigate a bug in your program.

Comment: You are on the right track, AVR-GCC treats doubles as the same as floats (32 bits). http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc

Comment: @user2461391: Thanks. That is that, then: Since the compiler does not support `double` correctly, the code does not perform as required by the C and C++ standards, and the value cannot be represented any more precisely. The OP needs a new compiler or needs to accept the lack of precision.

Comment: Hidden in the lack of support for 8-byte double is some good advice.

Comment: SO what do you suggest to do?Leave it as it is?

Comment: it does print 958.2540283203125 even immediately after the initialization

Comment: @kyrpav: You must either accept the reduced precision, get a different compiler with proper floating-point support, or write code to provide the accuracy you need with the reduced precision.

Comment: The advice I was hinting at was to seriously reconsider your choice of platform.  You are wondering why there is no support for 64-bit floating point math on an 8-bit microcontroller with no hardware floating point support.  I'm suggesting different expectations: you should be amazed that you have float support of any form on a micro.  And also, you should be trying to get rid of all float operations because your code size will benefit greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
    d = 557.254000000d;
```

Comment: error: invalid suffix "D" on floating constant.it does not understand it and give syntax error